# BCP multiprocessing

Tags: bcp

I am looking for some improvement in the below process .

1. There will be flat file formed after a process
2. The flat file will be of big size, currently we are `BCP`'ing the data in to table as 1000 batch.
3. huge the file the process is delayed
4. The table that we are `BCP`'ing now are in single partition

Suggestion from my side:

1. Split the table into multiple partition
2. `BCP` the data as parallel process so that the `BCP` time will be reduced

Database I am using us sybase. Do you think what I am suggesting is right or is there any way to improve the process. Note: We are dropping the index on the table `BCP`ing the data and recreating the index to improve the performance

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

BCP into, and out of, a pipe (FIFO). 
See http://scn.sap.com/community/database/blog/2010/08/03/is-bcp-supported-with-fifos-yes-finally